# How to install scikit-learn from github

Tags: python, github, scikit-learn

I noticed that somewhere in the library of scikit-learn there is a bug according to forums and i saw that they github has a developed library for scikit-learn. I am hoping they fixed the bugs there so I want to install scikit-learn on my ubuntu and raspbian os. I want to install the latest version 0.18 scikit-learn for python 2.7. can anybody help me. thank you in advance

Comment: side note - what was the bug that you faced? is it easily overcome?

Comment: I cannot load the trained classifier. I trained it in ubuntu but when loaded to raspbian it it does not load. it says  "did not recognize loaded array Layout".

Comment: This is a different issue - I think the issue is saving data on one platform then opening on another will cause all sorts of issues. For example, you can save a pickle in any fashion on your local machine and open it on a remote server - this is a known behaviour with pickle, this puts the onus on you as the dev to ensure you have the compatibility. Try creating another question with this error or search `pickle` for your platforms - also explain if you are using the sklearn model dump or just the standard pickle.

Comment: so there is an issue with pickle on different platforms.. that is new to me. I am using sklearn model dump by the way

Comment: I have not tried this myself but this [link](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=90544) about using `anaconda` to install sklearn etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Literally on the `readme` file here on the [scikit-learn](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn#source-code) git page.

For the latest branch i.e. `0.18x` you have to do the following

- git clone the repo as in the link I have provided or run the following
  `git clone https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn.git`
- checkout the latest branch with `git checkout origin/0.18.X`

You should now have the latest and greatest.

Note that this branch may have functions that will break your current scripts that depend on `sklearn`.

Comment: is this compatible with 32bit python?

Comment: It should do. But I have not tested this idea - did you try to install?

Comment: I installed the development scikit learn but it did not solve the problem i matched the ubuntu os and raspbian to no avail